# How to Two table sum calculate

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a two table.

I want to use the chart_num value for two tables.

**Table hospital_payment_data**

```
id  chart_num   treatment_fees_difference    treatment_fees_check_division
1        9        200000                             test
2        9        100000                             test
```

**Table advenced_payment**

```
id  chart_num      advenced_amount
1      9                100000
```

**I want result**

```
COUNT       if_treatment_fees_check_division     sum_init_amount
  2                      200000                  100000
```

I want treatment_fees_check_division = 'test' count 
and
I want treatment_fees_check_division = 'test' condition  sum treatment_fees_difference + advenced_amount
How can I achieve **I want result**? Would you please provide the solution?

Comment: Please be more specific. What formula do you want to use to calculate `if_treatment_fees_check_division` and `sum_init_amount`?

Comment: yes condition is treatment_fees_check_division(where treatment_fees_check_division = 'test')           
 sum treatment_fees_difference and advenced_amount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a query as below-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=53f1e3fc0c1655ef78f060f7304fc450)

Note: As per your condition and data, SUM of if_treatment_fees_check_division should be 300000

```
SELECT A.chart_num,
COUNT(*) COUN,
SUM(CASE 
    WHEN treatment_fees_check_division = 'test' THEN treatment_fees_difference 
    ELSE 0 
END) if_treatment_fees_check_division,
(
    SELECT SUM(advenced_amount) 
    FROM advenced_payment 
    WHERE chart_num = A.chart_num
) sum_init_amount
FROM hospital_payment_data A
GROUP BY A.chart_num
```

Comment: Thank you very much but 
if_treatment_fees_check_division result is ok 
but sum_init_amount is result 200000 I want sum_init_amount result  100000

Comment: Hi @user1082164, sorry i missed that. Please check my updated query with inline Sub Query. You can check the updated DEMO as well.

Comment: Thank you but There's one problem. I have completed the question in your comment.

Comment: I Solved it. Thank you. Very Thank you

Comment: I have a one question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211044/discussion-between-mkrabbani-and-user1082164).